# Pass parameter to callback function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

My code

// do ajax request and get JSON response

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {  
    result = data.results[i];
    // do stuff and create google maps marker    
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(result.lat, result.lng),   
        map: map,  
        id: result.id  
    });  
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
        createWindow(marker.id); //<==== this doesn't work because marker always points to the last results when this function is called
    });  

}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
with ({ mark: marker }) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {  
        createWindow(mark.id);
    });
}
```

An example that demonstrates the use of `with`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 1000);
}
```

The above will log `10` ten times.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    with ({ foo: i }) {
        setTimeout(function() { console.log(foo); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

This will log `0` to `9`, as desired, thanks to `with` introducing a new scope.

JavaScript 1.7 has a `let` statement that is nicer, but until that is widely supported, you can use `with`.

And use `var` for your variables.

Answer (score 4):

The [classic closure problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104321/how-to-assign-event-callbacks-iterating-an-array-in-javascript-jquery/1104440#1104440) strikes again!

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(id) {
    return function(){
      createWindow(id); //<==== this doesn't work because marker always points to the last results when this function is called
    }
  }(marker.id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a closure problem.  See these questions:

- [google maps api all markers opening the same infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078309/google-maps-api-all-markers-opening-the-same-infowindow)
- [google maps trouble closures passing by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829353/google-maps-trouble-closures-passing-by-reference)
- [dynamically adding listeners to google maps markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220063/dynamically-adding-listeners-to-google-maps-markers)

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var marker = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {  
    result = data.results[i];
    // do stuff and create google maps marker    
    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({  
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(result.lat, result.lng),   
        map: map,  
        id: result.id  
    });  
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', example(marker[i].id));  

}
```

create new function

```
function example(my_window){
    return function(){
        createWindow(my_window);
    }
}
```