# Passing arguments to callback function inside google.maps.event.addListener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to pass arguments inside `google.maps.event.addListener`

I know I can do it like this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    callback(param1, param2);
});
```

but since I'm declaring markers inside a loop, I'm getting linting errors :

> Dont make functions within a loop

I tried adding them like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseover', toggleOpacity, param1, param2);
```

but it's not working ..

Anyone knows how I can pass arguments without making use of a second function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass parameter to callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663309/pass-parameter-to-callback-function)

Comment: dont think so . that should be fixed by passing this.id forward . i cant add function() {} there because of linting ...

Comment: Well your second attempt `google.maps.event.addListener(country, 'mouseover', toggleOpacity, param1, param2);` isn't going to work because executes the function and uses the return value as a function pointer to a function to call on the mouseover event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a function without it running right away?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638361/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-function-without-it-running-right-away)